# recaptcha_v3 actions can be tracked in feature?

Tags: captcha

I using the recaptcha_v3 module in Drupal 7, is there are anyway we can track the actions we are adding part of the feature or it should be added through the hook_update_N() when we push from one environment to another?

Comment: Have you tried the Features module? Or Configuraiton Management? See https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/48219/how-can-i-isolate-content-from-configuration-in-the-database/48223

Comment: Since its a drupal 7 I have tried with the Features module but i don't find the actions are tracked anywhere in the feature.

Comment: There's a Configuration Management release for D7, alpha. You may try it: https://www.drupal.org/project/configuration

Comment: @sanzante thanks for your suggestion, i will try it.